# Mysql XML table export command line

Tags: mysql, command-line, export

Maybe I'm not seeing something here but WHY would this command line work perfectly fine and provide a result set when run on a LINUX command line but when executed from a WINDOWS command line it fails dismally and returns nothing?

```
mysql -hHOSTNAME -uroot -p --xml -e 'SELECT * FROM db.table' > c:\temp\output.xml
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows command line does not recognize `'` as a quote character, so your statement parameter becomes `SELECT` (truncated at the 1st space).

You must use `"` instead, as Heena Hussain suggested.

Comment: Damn it! Thats the one, the double quote fixed it.  
Didnt even think that was the issue or to try double quotes.  I suppose this is one of those issues of working by yourself, the lack of the extra eyes

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try this...

```
C:\>mysql -u <userid> -p<password> -e "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%version%'" –-xml
```

and this...

```
mysql -u db_user -p db_name --xml -e "SELECT * FROM table_name" > table_name.xml
```